# Behavior of DataFields without a corresponding MERGEFIELD

Tags: docx4j

If I pass in a map of fields to the `getConsolidatedResultCrude()` method, but some of the DataFields in the map don't have a corresponding MERGEFIELD in the docx file, will the unmapped data just be ignored, or will docx4j complain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a DataField in the map doesn't have a corresponding MERGEFIELD in the docx file, this won't matter (ie it will be ignored).

In contrast, if a MERGEFIELD is encountered without corresponding data, a warning will be logged.